# Detecting shape delection in PPT

Tags: powerpoint, vsto, office-interop, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

in a VSTO project is possible intercept shape delete event?

I've try to intercept key press with "[mousekeyhook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook)" but without success.

Anyone have suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just a thought off top of head: To delete something, you must select it, so a selection change event will fire *before* the user can delete anything. Then once the shape is deleted, the current selection will change so you should again get a selection change event. If you record the shape's ID with each selection change event, and also check for the id of the previously selected shape and test to see if it still exists on the slide, you can determine which shape was deleted (if that's important).

Comment: Yeah, @SteveRindsberg is right. Use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/PowerPoint.Application.WindowSelectionChange for that.

Answer (score 0):

VSTO (nor the PowerPoint object model) doesn't provide any events for that out of the box.